# how do I get charAt() to check every first letter after splitting a string?

Tags: javascript

How do I get `charAt()` to display the letters of all the splitted values at index=0? I don't know what to write before the `.charAt()` in order to arrange to give me the letters of all the splitted values at index=0, it gives me one value though:

```
<button onclick="occurence('The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy 
dog')">Go</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
function occurence(str) {
//conversion to string to make get the value of every single letter
var spl = str.split("");
//loop to subtract from spl.length to get value for chartAt
for (i = 0; i < spl.length; i++) {
}
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = spl[i - spl.length].charAt(0) + 
"<br>";
}
</script>
```

Comment: What are you expecting the demo innerHTML to be? The character *codes* (ascii value) separated by `<br>`, or just a list of characters separate by `<br>`?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish? You're splitting the string into an array where each character becomes an item in the array, so using `charAt(0)` seems pointless. Your `for` loop does nothing but cause `i` to have the same value as `spl.length`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is the working version of your code:

```js
function occurence(str) {
  //conversion to string to make get the value of every single letter
  var spl = str.split(" ");
  //loop to subtract from spl.length to get value for chartAt
  var firstLetters = []
  for (i = 0; i < spl.length; i++) {
    firstLetters.push(spl[i].charAt(0));
  }
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = firstLetters.join("<br>");
}
```

```html
<button onclick="occurence('The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog')">Go</button>

<p id="demo"></p>
```

First of all `The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog` text from your question was giving me some error. There was probably an encoding issue so I rewrite it by hand.

You should split your string with `str.split(" ")` not `str.split("")`.

You need to define an array like this `var firstLetters = []` to use it as a stack inside to for loop.

You get the first letter of a word by `spl[i].charAt(0)` and you need to push this letter with `firstLetters.push(spl[i].charAt(0))` inside the for loop.

Lastly you join `firstLetters` stack and display inside the demo tag with: `document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = firstLetters.join("") + "<br>"`

Comment: According to his comments in the code, N00B is looking to: "get the value of every single letter" within the string.

Comment: You don't need to push into array and then join. That's inefficient. You can just use a string and then modify the html.

Comment: @PankajShukla What do you mean with "inefficient"? Give me the evidence that my code is less efficient (in terms of performance) than your code please...

Comment: @mertyildiran Check out this perf test `http://jsben.ch/#/ir85X`. Is shows that string concat is faster than array#push and array#join. Modern browsers are way faster in concatenation.

Comment: @PankajShukla first of all, you edited your answer after our conversation. Fortunately, I found your original answer. [This jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mertyildiran/3z10rvpd/) runs your code and mine 1000 times and calculates the elapsed time for each. Yours is ~198 milliseconds while mine is ~32 milliseconds. This is why you shouldn't update the DOM inside a for loop (if it's not compulsory). So mine was better...

Comment: @mertyildiran I said that whether to modify the DOM inside the for loop or not was not the `core` part of the problem. Now when you suggested that you are faster. I showed you that my modified code is faster than yours. You are comparing old code with your new code. Compare the latest code. Looks like you downvoted me. Do you not see the reason why your latest code is slower than my latest code?

Comment: @mertyildiran Please see the reasoning and logic and don't downvote me.

Answer (score 0):

I apologize for not explaining my question properly. I was trying to make a program that takes input in two textboxes in one the user enters text in which they would want to know how many of the specified characters entered in the second textbox are found in the text entered in the first textbox. A lot of you told me to split with " " not "" but " " would not have given me the charAt(0) of ever single character. I have built the program and used mertyildiran's code to get the charAt(0) for every single letter.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
   <head>
   <title>Page Title</title>
   </head>
   <body>

   enter text:
   <input id="enteredText" type="text">

   enter text to be checked:
   <input id="toBeChecked" type="text">

   <button onclick="occurence()">Go</button>

   <p id="demo"></p>

   <script>
   function occurence() {
   //value of entered text to be checked
   var inpTextToCheck = document.getElementById("toBeChecked").value
   //value of entered text
   var inpText = document.getElementById("enteredText").value

   //conversion to string to make get the value of every single letter
   var spl = inpText.split("");


   //loop to get all letters at index = 0(all letters actually, since they are 
   now an array)
   var allLetters = []
   for (i = 0; i < spl.length; i++) {
    allLetters.push(spl[i].charAt(0));
   }
   var inpLetters = allLetters.join();

   //conversion of letter or word entered by user to RegExp so it can be used as 
   a variable in match()
   var re = new RegExp(inpTextToCheck, 'gi');

   //number of times the text to be checked is found in the entered text
   numOfOccurences = (inpText.match(re) || []).length

   // if the text to be checked is a number and is found once in the entered 
   text
   if (numOfOccurences == 1 && inpTextToCheck >= 0 || inpTextToCheck <= 0) {
   document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "The number " + inpTextToCheck
   + " was found once in the entered text"
   }
   //if the text to be checked is a number and is found more than once in the 
   entered text
   else if (inpTextToCheck >= 0 || inpTextToCheck <= 0) {
   document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "The number " + inpTextToCheck + 
   " was found "
   + numOfOccurences + " times in the entered text"
   }
  //if the text to be checked is a letter and was found once in the entered text
  else if (inpTextToCheck.length == 1 && numOfOccurences == 1) {
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "The letter " + '"' + 
  inpTextToCheck + '"' + " was found once in the entered text"
  }
  //if the text to be checked is a letter and was found more than once in the 
  entered text
  else if (inpTextToCheck.length == 1 && numOfOccurences > 1) {
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "The letter " + '"' + 
  inpTextToCheck + '"' + " was found " + numOfOccurences+ " times in the entered 
  text"
  }
  //if the text to be checked is found once and is a word or letter combination
  else if (inpTextToCheck.length > 1 && numOfOccurences == 1) {
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "The word or letter combination " 
  + '"' + inpTextToCheck + '"' + " was found once in the entered text"
  }
  //if the text to be checked is found more than once and is a word or letter 
  combination
  else if (inpTextToCheck.length > 1 && numOfOccurences > 1) {
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "The word or letter combination " 
  + '"' + inpTextToCheck + '"' + " was found " + numOfOccurences + " times in 
  the entered text"
  }
  if (numOfOccurences == 0) {
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = '"' + inpTextToCheck + '"' + " was 
  not found in the entered text";
    }
  }

  </script>
  </body>
  </html>
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to do this:
1. Split the passed argument with `" "` NOT `""`
2. Collect the value of each word's first letter in the string in the loop and then update html of `demo` outside the loop.
3. To get the first letter of the split string do `spl[i].charAt(0)`

```js
function occurence(str) {
        //conversion to string to make get the value of every single letter
        var spl = str.split(" ");
        var str ="";
        //loop to subtract from spl.length to get value for chartAt
        for (i = 0; i < spl.length; i++) {
            str += spl[i].charAt(0) + "<br>";
        }
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = str;
        
 }
```

```html
<button onclick="occurence('The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog')">Go</button>
<p id="demo"></p>
```

Comment: Why you are updating the DOM in each iteration. It's inefficient/costly. Also storing the letters at a stack is more elegant.

Comment: Modified though it was an optimization, not part of core question.

Comment: You updated your answer after my comment and still you are claiming that yours was better under my answer's comment section... [This jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mertyildiran/3z10rvpd/) runs your code and mine 1000 times and calculates the elapsed time for each. Yours is ~198 milliseconds while mine is ~32 milliseconds. So mine was better...

Comment: @mertyildiran Never claimed that my old code was faster than your code. Climing that in our latest code, mine is faster. Did you see the link I provided which compares latest code? Not sure why you downvoted me? Who can claim that modifying DOM in a for loop is faster?

Comment: @mertyildiran OP was asking how to get first letter of every word of the string, NOT how not to modify DOM inside the loop.

Answer (score -1):

You can use `String.prototype.match()` with `RegExp` `/\b\w/g` to match word boundary followed by one word character, chain `Array.prototype.join()` with parameter `"<br>"` to resulting array.

```html
<button onclick="occurrence('The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog')">Go</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
  function occurrence(str) {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = str.match(/\b\w/g).join("<br>")
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

If I get you correctly, you want to display the letters at index 0 of the individual words of the string `str`.

You should split on `" "` not `""`, and the `innerHTML` of `#demo` should be updated in the loop not outside.

I have modified your code to achieve what I think you're talking about.

```js
function occurence(str) {
    //conversion to string to make get the value of every single letter
    var spl = str.split(" "); // split on " " not ""
    //loop to subtract from spl.length to get value for chartAt
    for (i = 0; i < spl.length; i++) {
        // innerHTML of #demo should be updated in the loop not outside
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML += spl[i].charAt(0) + "<br>";
    }
}
```

```html
<button onclick="occurence('The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog')">Go</button>

<p id="demo"></p>
```